# Web Service => Web Reference

Tags: c#, webservice

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2015, C#, app windows forms, al servicio que me conecto es de tipo XML

Estoy consumiendo dos web service los cuales están implementados por Web Reference
El primer web service sirve para validar un xml firmado hablemos en el escenario de que todo vaya bien:

Primer WS: Validación de xml si valido sin problemas recibo una respuesta que dice "RECIBIDA", muestro código.

```
private void btnFirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a new XML document.
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            var uidCert = GetCertificateByPath();

            using (var clientWs = new EnviarFactura.ec.gob.sri.celcer.RecepcionComprobantesOfflineService())
            {
                clientWs.Url = $"{sri_url}{"RecepcionComprobantesOffline"}";
                clientWs.ClientCertificates.Add(uidCert);

                FirmaXades firmaXades = new FirmaXades(SignMethod.RSAwithSHA1, DigestMethod.SHA1);

                // Cargue un archivo XML en el objeto XmlDocument.
                string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testfiles.path"].ToString();
                xmlDoc.Load(Path.Combine(path, "Factura_001-500-000000005_60.01_XXXXXXXXXXXXX.xml"));

                XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xmlDoc.InnerXml);
                var result = doc.Elements("infoTributaria")
                    .Elements("claveAcceso").ToArray();
                _claveAcesso = result[0].Value;

                xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

                firmaXades.SetContentEnveloped(xmlDoc);
                firmaXades.Sign(uidCert, SignMethod.RSAwithSHA1);
                RecepcionComprobantesOfflineService pf = new RecepcionComprobantesOfflineService();
                clientWs.validarComprobanteCompleted += ClientWsOnValidarComprobanteCompleted;
                clientWs.validarComprobanteAsync(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firmaXades.Document.InnerXml));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{ex.Message}", @"Prueba");
        }
    }

    string _mensaje = string.Empty;
    string _estadoAurorizacion = string.Empty;

    private void ClientWsOnValidarComprobanteCompleted(object sender, validarComprobanteCompletedEventArgs validarComprobanteCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        if (validarComprobanteCompletedEventArgs != null)
        {
            _estado = validarComprobanteCompletedEventArgs.Result.estado;

            if (_estado == "RECIBIDA")
            {
                using (var client2Ws = new EnviarFactura.ec.gob.sri.celcer1.AutorizacionComprobantesOfflineService())
                {
                    client2Ws.Url = $"{sri_url}{"AutorizacionComprobantesOffline"}";
                    client2Ws.autorizacionComprobanteCompleted += Client2WsOnAutorizacionComprobanteCompleted;
                    //var response2 =
                    client2Ws.autorizacionComprobanteAsync(_claveAcesso);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

En la implementación del Web reference se creo la clase a partir del xml, estoy usando un método asincrono que es el siguiente:

```
public void validarComprobanteAsync(byte[] xml) {
        this.validarComprobanteAsync(xml, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void validarComprobanteAsync(byte[] xml, object userState) {
        if ((this.validarComprobanteOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.validarComprobanteOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnvalidarComprobanteOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("validarComprobante", new object[] {
                    xml}, this.validarComprobanteOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OnvalidarComprobanteOperationCompleted(object arg) {
        if ((this.validarComprobanteCompleted != null)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.validarComprobanteCompleted(this, new validarComprobanteCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public new void CancelAsync(object userState) {
        base.CancelAsync(userState);
    }
```

Tengo la necesidad de trabajar con los métodos asincronos por que no se cuanto tiempo desmore en responder el primer web service de validación y cuando este responda necesito mandar un parámetro al segundo web service que también lo quiero trabajar asincronamente.

El problema que tengo es que no se hacer una implementación adecuada que me permita saber cuando respondio el primer Ws para poder llamar al segundo WS
En el código que les muestro se me ocurrio llamar al método clientWs.validarComprobanteCompleted, que me imagino que es cuando se completo la petición al primer WS y este respondió.

Ahora en el evento clientWs.validarComprobanteCompleted llamo al segundo WS pasandole un parámetro el cual no he podido capturar el mensaje que este responde.

```
private void ClientWsOnValidarComprobanteCompleted(object sender, validarComprobanteCompletedEventArgs validarComprobanteCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        if (validarComprobanteCompletedEventArgs != null)
        {
            _estado = validarComprobanteCompletedEventArgs.Result.estado;

            if (_estado == "RECIBIDA")
            {
                using (var client2Ws = new EnviarFactura.ec.gob.sri.celcer1.AutorizacionComprobantesOfflineService())
                {
                    client2Ws.Url = $"{sri_url}{"AutorizacionComprobantesOffline"}";
                    client2Ws.autorizacionComprobanteCompleted += Client2WsOnAutorizacionComprobanteCompleted;
                    //var response2 =
                    client2Ws.autorizacionComprobanteAsync(_claveAcesso);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Client2WsOnAutorizacionComprobanteCompleted(object sender, autorizacionComprobanteCompletedEventArgs comprobanteCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        if (comprobanteCompletedEventArgs != null)
        {
            //foreach (var encontrado in comprobanteCompletedEventArgs.Result.autorizaciones.ToList())
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show(_estadoAurorizacion = encontrado.estado);
            //    foreach (var x in encontrado.mensajes)
            //    {
            //        MessageBox.Show(_mensaje = x.mensaje1);
            //    }
            //}
            var result = comprobanteCompletedEventArgs.Result.autorizaciones.Select(x => x.estado);
        }
    }
```

El método async de este es el siguiente:

```
public void autorizacionComprobanteAsync(string claveAccesoComprobante) {
        this.autorizacionComprobanteAsync(claveAccesoComprobante, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void autorizacionComprobanteAsync(string claveAccesoComprobante, object userState) {
        if ((this.autorizacionComprobanteOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.autorizacionComprobanteOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnautorizacionComprobanteOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("autorizacionComprobante", new object[] {
                    claveAccesoComprobante}, this.autorizacionComprobanteOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OnautorizacionComprobanteOperationCompleted(object arg) {
        if ((this.autorizacionComprobanteCompleted != null)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.autorizacionComprobanteCompleted(this, new autorizacionComprobanteCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

public new void CancelAsync(object userState) {
        base.CancelAsync(userState);
    }
```

¿Cual es la implementación adecuada para trabajar métodos asincronos en el cual uno espere la respuesta del otro para poder llamar al segundo web service?

Answer (score 0):

podrias probar utilizando `ContinueWith`, para mas informaciones podes visitar el siguiente [enclance](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__)

un ejemplo de como podria ser es :

```
public async Task<T> MyAsyncFun() {
    T value = await ...
    return value;
}

MyAsyncFun().ContinueWith(...
```

se que no es mucho pero espero que te sea de ayuda, exitos

**EDIT**

Me olvidava especificar que seria un metodo equivalente al `promise.then()` utilizado en Javascript